# Why vector<int> variable returned by const ref doesn't work

Tags: c++, vector, constants, ref

Here is my function:

```
const vector<int>& getVInt(){
  vector<int> vint;
  (...)
  return vint;
}
```

And,

```
  vector<int> x = getVInt();
```

returns:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'std::out_of_range'
>  what(): vector::_M_range_check

and

```
const vector<int>& x = getVInt();
```

returns nothing (a vector with a size different from 0 but with no value when I use x.at(i) ).

I looked for in forum but answers about temprorary and const ref doesn't help me to understand that.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `entitiesIds`?

Comment: It was a mistake, it is vint.

Comment: Does the warning your compiler should be emitting *not* hint to the problem? (clang 3.4: `Reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'vint' returned)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are returning a reference to a local object. That's undefined behavior. Return by copy instead, the copy will be elided thanks to [RVO (return value optimization)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

```
std::vector<int> getVInt(){
    std::vector<int> vint;
    // …
    return vint;
}
```

Comment: Yes but I've used const.

Comment: @FarorTahal, doesn't matter.

Comment: The object is gone after you exit the function. Doesn't matter that you hold a const reference to a dead object.

Comment: Thank you FKaria, I've understood. @Jeffrey Thus, Jeffrey, with RVO we don't care to return variable by ref or not?

Comment: @FarorTahal If you returned by value, binding to a `const` reference would extend the returned object's lifetime. But you don't return by value.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yet I return by value: "return vint". But I think I've understood, to return by const ref, before I have to bind the returned value to a const ref, or the returned variable have to be a preexisting variable like an object's attribut for instance. Isn't it?

Comment: @FarorTahal This: `const vector<int>& getVInt()` means you return a reference, not by value.

Comment: @FarorTahal, just return by value and make a copy. That's the easiest and most efficient ways. What juanchopanza refers to, is the fact that temporary binded to reference (both `const` and non-`const`) will extend the lifetime of the object. In this specific case it doesn't change much and I think it's much cleaner by value.

Comment: Even if `RVO` doesn't apply, it will be moved thanks to move-semantics in C++11.

Comment: @Jefffrey and @M M Ok, thank you. So with RVO or move-semantics in C++11, it doesn't change much for memory to return by value or ref?

Comment: @TahalFaror, it's no time with RVO and constant complexity with move-semantics for `std::vector`. So, yeah, you should definitely don't worry about performance here.

Comment: So in which case I should use return of const ref or non-const ref?